# Routing for controllers with multiple words in in Rails 4

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I've just upgraded to Rails 4 and found an unexpected behaviour with routing.

We have a controller named EmailPreviewController. The routing for this was:

```
get "/emailpreview", controller: 'EmailPreview', action: :index
```

however after upgrading to Rails 4 this throws the following error when the environment is loaded:

```
'EmailPreview' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use
```

I've looked at [the page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use) it suggests however there isn't any indication that it's incorrect to use a controller with a CamelCase name.

If I change the controller to lower case there isn't any problem:

```
# this works fine
get "/emailpreview", controller: 'emailpreview', action: :index
```

Is this expected behaviour? Is it not possible to use camelcase controller names now or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to this was somewhat counter-intuitive. I assume it's as-designed but it's not what I would have expected.

### In Rails 3, you could specify controllers using the object's name

In Rails 3, you could pass the name of the controller object and Rails would find its way to it:

```
get "emailpreview", controller: 'EmailPreview', action: :index
```

would find its way to the `EmailPreviewController` contained within `email_preview.rb`.

### however in Rails 4 you need to pass controller names in snake-case

In Rails 4 it seems that you need to pass the name of the controller object in snake-case:

```
get "emailpreview", controller: 'email_preview', action: :index
```

This will make its way to the `EmailPreviewController` contained within `email_preview.rb`.

Also see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing (though this doesn't explain much in this particular instance)