# 'sarlLegalStatuses' is not a supported controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I'm struggling with the following error when using the camelcased version of my ressource named `sarlLegalSatuses`

this is the error i get :

```
in check_controller_and_action': 'sarlLegalStatuses' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems.
```

my routing :

```
ils.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'sarlLegalStatuses#new'

  resources :sarlLegalStatuses
end
```

Using snake case fixed the issue, but as I'm going further in the code, this start to be quite annoying. I noticed people havinf problem with plural forms of words ending with "s" so I added the following inflections without success, as you can see :

Acti

```
veSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  #   inflect.acronym 'RESTful'
  inflect.uncountable %w(sarl legal)
  inflect.irregular 'status', 'statuses'
end
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why don't you follow the convention?

Comment: Can you be more specific because I don't see how I don't follow the convention ? I'm am trying to follow the convention, that is why I would prefer not using snake case in my code.

Comment: in routes `sarlLegalStatuses` should be like `sarl_legal_statuses` and you controller name should be `sarl_legal_statuses_controller.rb`

Comment: Just use snake case, just as *Rails convention* tells you to:
`root 'sarl_legal_statuses#new'`, `resources :sarl_legal_statuses`

Comment: So my question seems to be more like: "Why do you prefer your right-according-to-you convention over well established and relied upon Ruby on Rails framework convention?"

Comment: it seems that I am not being clear, I thought camelCase was RAILS convention because I didn't find any "official" source telling me to put snake_case (which is usually for filenames). Also they never use multiple-words controller names in their examples :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong thing here is you try to go against Ruby on Rails convention. Stick to the RoR convention, use snake case in your routes:

```
root 'sarl_legal_statuses#new'
resources :sarl_legal_statuses
```

and you'll be all right. What's more, the code will be more friendly for those who might enter the project in the future. So the experiments with camel case are completely pointless.

Comment: I thought camelCase was the convention, as I don't see any traces of that information and usualy snake_case in used for filenames

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to snake-case your controller names in the code, see [routing-for-controllers-with-multiple-words-in-in-rails-4 on stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607305/routing-for-controllers-with-multiple-words-in-in-rails-4) but I have been reading lots of guides and naming conventions I it seems like they never mention this (which case to use) so I guess I just have to take commenters words for it.

Comment: Hm, it's strange. I doubt that for example Rails guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) advice to use camel case in routes.

Comment: I never said that, but I will edit to make it clearer

Comment: as a matter of fact I just searched the term "case" in the guide you pointed, to be 100% sure. No information about which case to use.

Comment: And they are always using singular-word-controllers in this guide, so I see your point now.

Comment: I'm doing a pull resquest right now to update the guide